# Bernoulli Principle and Cosmic Evolution

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, bernoulli-equation

How do we derive the Bernoulli principle from the Friedmann equation?

I've been asked to clarify why there is any connection at all. The Friedmann equation [is] a fluid equation. More succinctly, the equation of state is a perfect fluid solution obtained from the Friedmann equation. For reference

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state_(cosmology)

*As I've been told, we can answer our own questions. Yet we are told to show a working example, but when I tagged an answer on a post, I was scrutinised for not doing it the other way round, so I will post my working example below soon. Edit* I've been asked to put the posts as one. So here is my working example.

I will attempt to derive a Bernoulli principle from the Friedmann equation. At some parts it feels a bit poor as I have to smudge two results, such as applying a coefficient of 1/2 to a kinetic analogue term, and also by replacing a density term with a pressure term. Critique is asked for and welcomed.

We begin with a simple Friedmann equation, we introduce a mass term and then take through a density.

$(\frac{\dot{R}}{R})^2 = \frac{8 \pi G}{3}\rho$

Here I have chosen the pressureless and curvature free equation.

Where we treat the pressure with the same dimensions as density. Rearranging the radius, then providing a mass to the system, which would really be a sum of the masses,

$\dot{R}^2= \frac{8 \pi GR^2}{3}\rho$

$mv^2 = m\dot{R}^2= \frac{8 \pi GmR^2}{3}\rho$

As part of convention, we will want the mv^2 part to have a coefficient of 1/2. This means the middle term should also be an analogue kinetic term. We can show why it is a kinetic term by formulating a simple Lagrangian,

Take both sides away gives the general Lagrangian

$L = \frac{1}{2} m\dot{R}^2 - \frac{8 \pi GR^2}{3}\rho$

$(\rho +3P)$ arises in a Friedmann equation, by adding two Friedmann equations together, and it is really a relativistic correction. Replacing a pressure term directly (may) not be such a haphazzahard thing to do. I can reason why if asked.

Anyway, I will digress back to:

$\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{R}^2= \frac{8 \pi GmR^2}{3}\rho$

And by a simple smudging based on dimensions alone, replacing the density for the pressure $\rho \rightarrow P$ would give

$\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{R}^2= \frac{8 \pi GmR^2}{3}P$

And I'd want to divide the equation by the density. There is method to the madness. When we try to construct an equation, we do so with a goal in mind.

$\frac{1}{2}mv^2 \frac{R^3}{m}= \frac{1}{2}m\dot{R}^2 \frac{R^3}{m} = \frac{8 \pi GmR^2}{3}\frac{P}{\rho}$

Simplify:

$\frac{1}{2}v^2 R^3 = \frac{8 \pi GmR^2}{3}\frac{P}{\rho}$

Cleaning it up further

$\frac{1}{2}v^2 = \frac{8 \pi Gm}{3R}\frac{P}{\rho}$

Gm is easily identifiable as the gravitational parameter, and when weighted by R, yields a velocity^2. In this formulation, the pressure is treated with the same dimensions as density. Hence why the velocity^2 is required to make it fit the usual dimensions of a pressure ie. $MV^2L^{-3}$. We can let it be absorbed into the pressure, now defining the standard dimensions.

$\frac{1}{2}v^2 = \frac{8 \pi}{3}\frac{P}{\rho}$

If we add both sides, we get two crucial terms towards our goal trying to derive a Bernoulli principle;

$\frac{1}{2}v^2 + \frac{8 \pi}{3}\frac{P}{\rho}$

The Bernoulli equation is

$\frac{1}{2}v^2 + gz + \frac{P}{\rho} = C$

By convention, g is always the acceleration due to gravity. Since gz is a velocity^2 term, the most natural solution I can fathom is

$\frac{P}{\rho} = 1 - \frac{gz}{c^2}$

And so,

$\frac{gz}{c^2} = 1 - \frac{P}{\rho}$

And then

$gz = (1 - \frac{P}{\rho})c^2 = c^2 - \frac{P}{\rho}c^2$

Notice the last term? $c^2\frac{P}{\rho}$. We came to a similar term earlier, through the equation:

$\frac{1}{2}v^2 = \frac{8 \pi Gm}{3R}\frac{P}{\rho} = \frac{8 \pi c^2}{3}\frac{P}{\rho}$

It looks like in principle that we can replace this middle term for gz, and by doing so we get, by adding all the terms;

$\frac{1}{2}v^2 + gz + \frac{8 \pi c^2}{3}\frac{P}{\rho} = C$

Again, looking for critical responses, so long as they are constructive. I had to smudge a few results and so I'm not completely happy with it.

Comment: I think what the guidelines really mean for your question is this: you're not asking how to derive the Bernoulli principle from the Friedmann equation. You're asking about whether your particular derivation is right at a couple specific places. It would be in keeping with customs on this site for you to move your "answer" into the question and then be very clear and specific on what you want other people to answer.

Comment: I get confused with the red tape. I just want to make sure I am abiding by the rules. Okay, I shall move the question into the OP. Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s about refereeing a derivation.

Comment: Maybe before jumping right into the details, it would be helpful to explain in words why you think there's any connection at all between the Bernoulli & Friedmann equations.

Comment: Simple, the Friedmann equation [is] a fluid equation. More succinctly, the equation of state is a perfect fluid solution obtained from the Friedmann equation.

Comment: For reference https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state_(cosmology)

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to the reason this post was closed, cited as off-topic. I was reading the circumstances of an off-topic post to be closed, and in my humble opinion, none of the reasons fall into the circumstances of closure. Its almost like the closing moderator was searching for an explanation which looks more like an excuse. Off topic involves topics which are not physics related, or it may be deemed that a post is not suitable for similar reasons. This topic is physics related, and there are no immediate reasons that makes the post unacceptable to be viewed by the public.

Comment: Clarification please?

Comment: Is it improper that I asked for clarification?.It's just that I've noticed no one has answered my question.